# what is the alernative to SIG Maintainability Model Plugin in latest Sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I used to find SIG Maintainability Model Plugin very useful in sonarqube dashboard. But as shown in below link, it has been deprecated.

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SIG+Maintainability+Model+Plugin

Currently I am using sonarqube 4.5.1 .
Could anyone please suggest me, Is there any other plugin which can be used as replacement to this plugin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Has anyone used Technical Debt Evaluation (SQALE) plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SonarQube 4.5 comes with the SQALE software quality model built-in.
Unlike the SIGMM plugin, SQALE is based solely on issues, so you'll want to make sure you have the relevant common rules (related to duplications, complexity, &etc.) turned on. But beyond that, SQALE should fit the bill.

There are more details in the [4.5 docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/Technical+Debt), and if what you get by default in the platform isn't enough, there is a [commercial plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/sqale/) that will let you tune your SQALE model.

Comment: Thanks @g-ann-sonarsource-team